# Firebase - Swift 4: Message sent but not received

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

Ran `pod update` on the terminal to update my firebase. However i don't receive FCM's

This is my app delegate code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import StoreKit
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    override init() {
        super.init()
            FirebaseApp.configure()
            // not really needed unless you really need it FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        Auth.auth().signInAnonymously() { (authResult, error) in
            // ...
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

                let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                    options: authOptions,
                    completionHandler: {_, _ in })
            } else {
                let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                    UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
                application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            }

            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }





        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default



        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "gateway") as! gatewayViewController
       window!.rootViewController = viewController

        return true
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print message ID.
        // if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        //      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        //  }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        // Print message ID.
        //if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        //    print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        //}//

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
```

But when trying to send a message on my console.firebase.com it gets labeled as "Completed" but my iPhone 6S don't shows the notification.

Notifications are also enabled in app capabilities

I need your help

Answer (score 1):

I think you're not setting your APN token. Push your APNs token.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { //data -> String in
        return String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0)
    }

    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .unknown)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

Comment: This worked for me! I tried about 5 different tutorials, and 30 SO posts and finally I found the right combo. 

I'm going to link this in the comments on the tutorial I used that worked with your answer.