# Firebase Cloud Messaging notifications not being displayed on iOS device (foreground and background)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM to create and send push notifications for my iOS app.

**Dev Environment:**

- Xcode 11.3
- iPhone X running iOS 13.3
- Swift 5.2

**Pod Versions:**

- Firebase 6.14.0
- FirebaseMessaging 4.1.10
- FirebaseInstanceID 4.2.8

**Problem:**

Prior to running into an issue, I had setup my app to be able to receive notifications when the app was in both the background and the foreground. Very happy with myself I committed the code. After this point I have been unable to receive notifications in the foreground OR the background. Regardless of using whether the notification is sent from Cloud Messaging dashboard or POSTMAN, I receive a successful response but the notification never appears.

At first I thought I may have hit the notification quota but it is now 2 days post fact.

**To troubleshoot I have tried:**

1. Uninstalled and re-installed the app (Which refreshes the device token)
2. Moved `UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()` to before `FirebaseApp.configure()`
3. Downloaded a fresh GoogleService-Info.plist and replaced existing
4. Checked that bundle id's etc all match
5. Updated firebase pods to latest (FirebaseMessaging was at 4.1.9 if that helps)
6. Set `Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true`
7. Removed and Re-added the needed capabilities
8. Set `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` to both YES and NO
9. Set `shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true`
10. Set `useMessagingDelegateForDirectChannel = true`
11. Moved some logic from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions() to applicationDidBecomeActive()

**Code:**

Note: This is the unaltered code that originally worked for me.

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FBSDKCoreKit
import GoogleMaps
import SwiftLocation
import GooglePlaces
import Crashlytics
import GoogleSignIn
import Armchair
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseMessaging

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var swipeNavigationViewController: SwipeNavigationViewController!

    override init() {
        super.init()

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
        swipeNavigationViewController = SwipeNavigationViewController()
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool  {
        FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.error)
        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

        // Google Maps
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey(FireBaseConstants.GoogleAPIKey)
        GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey(FireBaseConstants.GoogleAPIKey)
        GeocoderRequest.GoogleOptions(APIKey: FireBaseConstants.GoogleAPIKey)

        let navigationViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: swipeNavigationViewController)
        navigationViewController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)

        self.window?.rootViewController = navigationViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        showAlertIfPointedTowardProductionDatabase()
        setupReviewRequest()

        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            // If granted comes true you can enabled features based on authorization.
            guard granted else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("UserID: \(UserManager.sharedManager.currentUser?.userID)")
                let pushManager = PushNotificationManager(userID: "currently_logged_in_user_id")
                pushManager.registerForPushNotifications()
            }
        }

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        return true
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        let handledByFB = ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)

        var handledByGoogle = false
        if !handledByFB {
            handledByGoogle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
        }

        let handled = handledByFB || handledByGoogle

        return handled
    }

    private func setupReviewRequest() {
        //Code...
    }

    // This method will be called when app received push notifications in foreground
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }
}
```

PushNotificationManager.swift

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseMessaging
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class PushNotificationManager: NSObject, MessagingDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    let userID: String
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    init(userID: String) {
        self.userID = userID
        super.init()
    }

    func registerForPushNotifications() {
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions) { (_, error) in
            guard error == nil else{
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
        }

        //get application instance ID
        InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching remote instance ID: \(error)")
            } else if let result = result {
                print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
            }
        }

        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        updateFirestorePushTokenIfNeeded()
    }

    func updateFirestorePushTokenIfNeeded() {
        if let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken {
            //            let usersRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users_table").document(userID)
            //            usersRef.setData(["fcmToken": token], merge: true)
            print("Remote instance ID token: \(token)")
        }
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print(response)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { //data -> String in
            return String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0)
        }

        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
        Messaging.messaging().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .unknown)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}
```

**This was setup using all of the following links (With a few others I forgot as well I'm sure):**

- https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/get-started-with-firebase-messaging-for-ios--cms-32126#comment-4345018783
- [Firebase - Swift 4: Message sent but not received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52468781/firebase-swift-4-message-sent-but-not-received/55058817#55058817)
- [Get push notification while App in foreground iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872088/get-push-notification-while-app-in-foreground-ios/40756206#40756206)
- https://www.iosapptemplates.com/blog/ios-development/push-notifications-firebase-swift-5

**Response Info:**

Postman:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 2586780331808083728,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:1578532253832479%2b1845e62b1845e6"
        }
    ]
}
```

Cloud Messaging:

[image: FCM Console]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by moving

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)
```

from PushNotificationManager to AppDelegate. Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

You can have `didRegisterForRemoteNotifications` in your controller layer. I have a private method in my controller that calls `registerForRemoteNotifications` as well. I instantiate my controller in AppDelegate so it's available right away, and I did have an issue when I tried to make the controller without a strong reference, probably having to do with weak delegate(s).

This is my entire `appDelegate`:

```swift
import UIKit
import Firebase

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var controller: FirebaseMessagingController!
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        self.controller = FirebaseMessagingController.shared
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

My controller's init:

```swift
    private init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(receiveToken(_:)),
            name: .tokenKey,
            object: nil)
        
        registerForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication.shared)
        requestNotificationPermissions { _ in } // TODO: move to more user friendly place
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? MessagingDelegate
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    }
    
    @objc private func receiveToken(_ notification: Notification) {
        
        guard let tokenDict = notification.userInfo as? [Notification.Name: String],
              let token = tokenDict[.tokenKey] else { return }
        self.token = token
        let apiTokenDict = ["token": token]
        if AuthService.shared.isLoggedIn {
            guard let user = AuthService.shared.user else { return }
            FirebaseDatabaseController().updateValues(for: APIRef.userRef(userId: user.userId).endpoint, with: apiTokenDict)
        }
        
    }
    
    private func registerForRemoteNotifications(_ application: UIApplication) {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    
    private func requestNotificationPermissions(completion: @escaping (Result<Bool, Error>) -> Void) {
        
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: { success, error in
                if success {
                    completion(.success(success))
                } else if let error = error {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                } else {
                    let error = NSError(domain: #function, code: 0)
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        )
        
    }
```

`didRegisterForRemoteNotifications` is also in my controller and receives the token:

```swift
    // set FirebaseMessaging service with apnsToken
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }
```

Edit: Actually, I have one more piece in AppDelegate, receiving the registration token, but hid it in an extension in my controller:

```swift
extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        guard let fcmToken = fcmToken else { return }
        let dataDict:[NSNotification.Name: String] = [.tokenKey: fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .tokenKey, object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
    }
    
}
```

Thinking about it, it's a weird choice since I could probably make the controller the messaging delegate and do it there without posting a notification....